# Functions with values in the unit disc

Tags: complex-analysis

I need help to answer this question.

What could we say about a polynomial $P(z)=a_0+\cdots+a_n z^n$ and the function $\exp\left(\frac{z+1}{z-1}\right)$ in the unit disc. What are the values of $\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ for $z$ in the unit disc? What do these functions map the unit disc into?

Comment: Your function $\frac{z+1}{z-1}$ is an example of a [Mobius transformation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation). In your case, it does not map the unit disk to itself (pick $z = .9$ for example). The reason being is that the $z-1$ in the denominator causes a divergence on the boundary of the unit disk. Based on [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_disk#The_open_unit_disk.2C_the_plane.2C_and_the_upper_half-plane), I'm inclined to think that your map maps the unit disk to the left half plane.